# android application connect to local server via mysql database?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, tomcat

I need to send data from an android application to the database, then access the same from a webpage with the help of a local server.

Can anyone suggest me how to link an android app to the database and view the same on a browser?

What are all the tools required?

If anyone can also help me by suggesting me a way or giving me suitable links of tutorials that can help, I'll be thankful!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the links

[android mysql connection](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/connect-mysql-database-from-android.html)[android spinner from mysql database](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/)

Answer (score 0):

To Connect to remote database you need to do certain steps

**STEP 1 :** Prepare data to send to Web Service in Android

**STEP 2:** Create MySQL Database in your local server.

**STEP 3:** Implement Web Service in your local server. Web Service is the code which used to process the data sent from android device. Insert the received data in to the database

**STEP 4:** Now you can access your database and display it in web browser.

Here is one of the [Good Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm)